# I'm trying to deploy an open source app on kubernetes, but the authentication doesn't work when deployed on google cloud

Tags: django, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm a total beginner, I haven't done anything like this before, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything related. I'm trying to deploy a voting app on google cloud on kubernetes. The problem is that the app has almost non-existent documentation, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. When I host the app locally, everything works as expected, but when I deployed it on kubernetes when I try to log in, the server throws a 403. Does anyone know what could cause it?

Here's the screenshot of the log:

[image]

Comment: would be useful if you could share the application you are trying to deploy. things you used to deploy this. like deploymnet.yaml, service.yaml etc.

Comment: https://github.com/grnet/zeus - it's this app
https://pastebin.com/4zLC6VjF - service yaml
https://pastebin.com/WGP71gB6 - deployment yaml

Comment: have you created the service.yaml and deployment.yaml files yourself. or was it from some documentation?

Comment: from the quick look what i can gather is, the dockerfile is exposing a different port than you are targetting in the service. that could be an issue. can you confirm if you can access the ui on the service?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I feel like the issue is with cookies, the sessionid cookie gets deleted after I log in on the service

Comment: How did you create  `gcr.io/ompps-voting/zeus:v2` image ?
Is it possible for you to share `deploy/config.yaml` file with us ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MbxJyE2N - it's the deploy.yaml

Comment: In my opinion this app isn't working as expected because you have 3 replicas.
If you scale your deployment to only one replica (`kubectl scale --replicas 1 deploy nginx-1`), it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pointed out the root cause in the comments section but for better visibility I decided to provide an answer.

**@smoczy123** noticed that the [Zeus app](https://github.com/grnet/zeus) doesn't work as expected with multiple replicas - more specifically, logging in doesn't work properly.

As a workaround we can create a `Deployment` with a single replica and scale the `Pod` vertically.
Additionally, it is possible to use [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) to set the requests automatically based on usage.